# Audi 100 1990 Sedan,cooler hose bulging = distaster waiting to happen, right?

Tags: troubleshooting, cooling-system

I must admit I haven't really paid attention to the coolant hoses, but today I noticed something. That coolant hose leading to the radiator doesn't look healthy with that bulge and there is also a white deposit that's most likely remains from coolant that's evaporated on hot engine parts.

[image: Coolant hose near thermostat]

Comment: Yes, that hose is not the most healthy and could fail, but a little bulging right after the clamp is also expected because of the flared pipe it's connected to. I'd recommend replacing it if the bulge feels like the hose layers are delaminating, but otherwise I don't think it's of imminent danger of failure. The white stuff is aluminum oxide, which happens when aluminum is in contact with air. I don't think it's related to a coolant leak.

Comment: I wasn't sure on that, but that aluminium oxide deposit seems to be concentrated around the hose.  I will see about brushing it off and seeing if it's just a coincidendce.

Comment: Most likely the bulge is from aluminum corrosion of the water neck underneath the hose, replace the hose and the water neck.

Answer (score 1):

> disaster waiting to happen

That is correct. I recommend that you replace the hose, both clamps and top up the coolant as soon as possible.

Comment: Thank you. On which clamps to replace them with, is there a preference? I know "standard hose clamps" are easy to work on, but is there something you should use for longevity?

Comment: Ordinary stainless steel worm-drive hose clamps sold at any auto parts store should work well.